# Derivative of exponential map on a Banach algebra

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, exponential-function

If we have a Banach algebra $A$ then the exponential map:
$$x\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
is well defined. Its derivative should be a map $A\to\mathrm{End}(A)$, however it is not clear to me how to actually calculate this map. For example the derivative of $x\mapsto x^2$ at point $x$ is the map $h\mapsto xh+hx$ and in general the derivative of $x^n$ will be $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k hx^{n-k}$, which prevents me from simplifying the sum.

> What is the derivative of the exponential map on a Banach algebra?

Comment: You have the derivatives of all the powers. There's not much simplification that can take place because of the lack of commutativity.

Comment: Unfortunate, but thank you.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15742/185147 provides the related result $$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}e^{x} ~=~ \int_0^1\!ds~e^{(1-s)x}\frac{dx}{d\lambda}e^{sx}$$ where $x$ is a function of $\lambda$.